# Type theory - category theory correspondence

Tags: ct.category-theory, type-theory

As explained [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory), simply typed lambda calculus can be viewed as a syntactic language for category theory. My question is, can the following modification make it equally well a formal syntactic language for 2-category theory?

It goes something like this: we have a universe $U$. For each $X : U$, we make $X$ into the universe of a simply typed lambda calculus by introducing the necessary [type formation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus). Maps $a \rightarrow b$ for $a, b : X$ are like maps of objects, under the usual correspondence.

In this setup, I would expect maps $X \rightarrow Y$ for $X, Y : U$ to correspond to functors in some way, and I would expect some kind of correspondence between type theories of this kind and $2$-categories.

More generally, I expect that introducing a higher universe is like passing from $n$-categories to $n+1$-categories. For a similar idea, applied instead to homotopy type theory, we might expect to get a model for $(\infty, 1)$-categories. Has anyone pursued an approach like this?

Comment: I really like the question, but it is more a research project than a MO question. A few steps in this direction have been made here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07442. It's hard to say how "definitive" this answer is to the problem of $(\infty,1)$-categories.
Another important reference, gathering the state of art up to 1991, is T. Streicher, Semantics of Type Theory: Correctness, Completeness, and Independence Results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the 2-categorical part there is Robert Seely's paper [Modelling computations: 2-categorical framework](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/WkAdj/LICS.pdf) from LICS 1987, and of course a bunch of papers that came afterwards [that cite the paper](https://scholar.google.si/scholar?cites=14241625227633821950&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=sl). As Ivan points out, the $(\infty, 1)$-aspects of computation are current research.

Comment: Is this really what the question is asking though? It's true that Seely uses a 2-categorical framework to model lambda calculus where the 2-cells are reductions. But in most type theories that I know, these reductions are necessarily invertible.

In a general 2-category I'm not sure there is a type theory which could be considered an "internal language of a 2-category".

Comment: Well, the author accepted my answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

Some references to some approachesthat exist in the literature have been given in Andrej's answer and Ivan's comment.  A couple others are Licata-Harper's work on [two-dimensional directed type theory](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/papers/2dtt/mfps.pdf) and Licata-Riley-Shulman's work on [fibrational frameworks](http://dlicata.web.wesleyan.edu/pubs/lsr17multi/lsr17multi-ex.pdf) (specifically the "mode theory" is a 2-dimensional type theory).